# How can I get the schema or row names of a table in soci?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, wrapper, soci

I am trying to accomplish [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493927/soci-print-out-all-data-in-table-by-rows), and I know how to do it indirectly...if I can get the schema of a table.

How can I do this using soci?

I have tried:

```
std::string i;
soci::statement st = (mSql->prepare <<
               "show create table tab;",
               soci::into(i));
st.execute();
while (st.fetch())
{   
         std::cout << i <<'\n';
}
```

but only "tab" gets printed.

I also tried this, from the Soci documentation in GitHub:

```
soci::column_info ci;
soci::statement st = (mSql->prepare_column_descriptions(table_name), into(ci));

st.execute();
while (st.fetch())
{
    // ci fields describe each column in turn
}
```

but was told that column_info is not a member of soci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following code [here](http://www.gonwan.com/tag/soci/)

```
soci::row v;
soci::statement st = (mSql->prepare << "SELECT * FROM tab", into(v));
st.execute(true);  /* with data exchange */
unsigned int num_fields = v.size();
std::cout << "fields: " << num_fields << std::endl;
num_fields = (num_fields <= 9) ? num_fields : 9;
unsigned long num_rows = (unsigned long)st.get_affected_rows();
std::cout << "rows: " << num_rows << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_fields; ++i) {
    const soci::column_properties &props = v.get_properties(i);
    std::cout << props.get_name() << '\t';
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The last things printed are the correct names of the columns.